# Inno Setup /components commandline switch does change the components selected

Tags: inno-setup

I have a Inno Setup script which has components and based on those components specific installation takes place. If I run manually, then installation works fine based on components checked. But if I run installer silently by passing `/components="component1"`, still it installs component which was installed before using the manual installation.

If I have installed `component2` manually and later try to install `component1` through command prompt, it still installs `component2` only. I'm not sure whether it is related to previous installation or not. Is there a way to pass components name as parameter through command line?

This is a sample script to mimic my problem.

```
[Types]
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation";
Name: "compact"; Description: "Compact installation";

[Components]
Name: "component1"; Description: "Component 1"; Types: custom
Name: "component2"; Description: "Component 2"; Types: compact
```

Syntax used on command line

```
$Release\mysetup.exe /verysilent /components="component2"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple `Types`, you have to first select the [`iscustom`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=typessection&anchor=iscustom) type before you can choose components. And in your case, as you actually cannot select the components (as you have no `iscustom` type), you basically only need to select the type using the [`/TYPE` switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=TYPE). The components will be selected along.

```
mysetup.exe /TYPE=custom
```

---

Basically, the command-line switches won't allow you doing, what the GUI cannot do. As the documentation for [`/COMPONENTS`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=COMPONENTS) says:

> If no custom type is defined, this parameter is ignored.